# PHP ORM style of querying

Tags: php, object-oriented, sql, coding-style, orm

Ok so I have made an ORM library for PHP. It uses syntax like so:

*(assume that $business_locations is an array)*

```
Business::type(Business:TYPE_AUTOMOTIVE)->
          size(Business::SIZE_SMALL)->
          left_join(BusinessOwner::table(), BusinessOwner::business_id(), SQL::OP_EQUALS, Business::id())->
          left_join(Owner::table(), SQL::OP_EQUALS, Owner::id(), BusinessOwner::owner_id())->
          where(Business::location_id(), SQL::in($business_locations))->
          group_by(Business::id())->
          select(SQL::count(BusinessOwner::id());
```

Which can also be represented as:

```
$query = new Business();
$query->set_type(Business:TYPE_AUTOMOTIVE);
$query->set_size(Business::SIZE_SMALL);
$query->left_join(BusinessOwner::table(), BusinessOwner::business_id(), SQL::OP_EQUALS, $query->id());
$query->left_join(Owner::table(), SQL::OP_EQUALS, Owner::id(), BusinessOwner::owner_id());
$query->where(Business::location_id(), SQL::in($business_locations));
$query->group_by(Business::id());
$query->select(SQL::count(BusinessOwner::id());
```

This would produce a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(`business_owners`.`id`)
FROM   `businesses`
       LEFT JOIN `business_owners`
         ON `business_owners`.`business_id` = `businesses`.`id`
       LEFT JOIN `owners`
         ON `owners`.`id` = `business_owners`.`owner_id`
WHERE  `businesses`.`type` = 'automotive'
       AND `businesses`.`size` = 'small'
       AND `businesses`.`location_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
GROUP  BY `businesses`.`id`
```

*Please keep in mind that the syntax might not be prefectly correct (I only wrote this off the top of my head)*

- Any way, what do you think of this style of querying?
- Is the first method or second better/clearer/cleaner/etc?
- What would you do to improve it?

Comment: I take it you've tried [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) and found them lacking or two heavy?  Maybe read this:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)

Comment: @orbling Ive never been a fan of annotations.

Answer (score 1):

One small improvement:

```
return $this
```

from each function.

Then you can chain them like this:

```
$query->set_type(Business:TYPE_AUTOMOTIVE)->set_size(Business::SIZE_SMALL);
```

Comment: It does, and it also returns a new instance from static calls.

Answer (score 0):

I know libraries like mysqli offer both styles. But to me that's slightly odd - there is one important difference between static and OO.

- 1st style (static) implies you can only do one query at a time.
- 2nd style
  (OO) implies you can do more than
  1.

So which is true? Personally I'd go with which ever is true.

Answer (score 0):

Both styles are horribly messy and verbose. I'd go with something much nicer like Doctrine.